# Running JUnit Tests on embedded glassfish 4 causing WARNING: AS-CDI-005

Tags: java, cdi, glassfish-4

I want to run JUnit Tests on an Embedded Glassfish 4 using CDI.
It end up with an endless loop of the following output:

WARNING: AS-CDI-005 Okt 22, 2013 4:49:23 PM org.glassfish.weld.BeanDeploymentArchiveImpl handleEntry

Can anybody help

Chears

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is putting your app name in the properties when creating the EJB container

```
Map<Object, Object> properties = new HashMap<Object, Object>(); 
properties.put(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "your_app_name");
EJBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
```